# Zend Framework DB Complex Where Or condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework

How can I do a SELECT like this  using Zend Framework Table.

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE (field1 = 0 AND field2 = 1) OR (field2 = 0 AND field3 = 1)`

Using just `$table->orWhere()` dont allow me to do multiple conditions inside of a parentheses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build complex queries:

```
// Zend_Db_Table
$this->getAdapter()->quoteInto('(field1 = 1 AND field2 =2) OR ...');
```

[Here](http://blog.motane.lu/2009/05/21/zend_db-quoteinto-with-multiple-arguments/) is a comprehensive article for more information.